# Python : find_all() return an empty list

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to make a bot that send me an email once a new product is online on a website.

I tried to do that with **requests** and **beautifulSoup**.

This is my code :

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://www.vinted.fr/vetements?search_text=football&size_id[]=207&price_from=0&price_to=15&order=newest_first'

headers = {'User-Agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.89 Safari/537.36"}

page = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

products = soup.find_all("div", class_="c-box")

print(len(products))
```

Next, I'll want to compare the number of products before and after my new request in a loop.

But when I try to see the number of products that I found, I get an empty list : `[]`

I don't know how to fix that ...

The div that I use is in others div, I don't know if it has a relation

Thanks by advance

Comment: I'm getting 403 when I ran your script. So, probably the soup object doesn't have the required dom to parse

Answer (score 1):

You have problem with the website that you are trying to parse.

The website in your code generates elements you are looking for(`div.c-box`) after the website is fully loaded, using javascript, at the client-side. So it's like:

Browser gets HTML source from server --(1)--> JS files loaded as browser loads html source --> JS files add elements to the HTML source --(2)--> Those elements are loaded to the browser

You cannot fetch the data you want by `requests.get` because `requests.get` method can only get HTML source at point (1), but the website loads the data at (2) point. To fetch such data, you should use automated browser modules such as `selenium`.

Comment: Thanks, I'm gonna see tutorials for selenium !

Answer (score 1):

You should always check the data.

Convert your BeautifulSoup object to string with `soup.decode('utf-8')` and write it on a file. Then check what you get from the website. In this case, there is no element with c-box class.

You should use `selenium` instead of `requests`.